# Is “before defining the derivative” a dangling participle in this sentence?

Tags: ambiguity, dangling-participles

Someone reviewing an article of mine claims that this sentence begins with a dangling participle.   Is that true?   Is the meaning of the sentence ambiguous?

> Before defining the derivative, it is useful to first define
>   nullability.

Comment: cf these examples: not dangling: "before doing A, you should do B", and dangling: "before doing A, B should be done".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The sentence does not even begin with a participial phrase, but with a prepositional phrase.

Ask someone if they think that "Before dinner, it is useful to define nullability" is a dangling participle as well.

And even more to the point, tell them that a dangling participle is not a mistake. It is just a label for a figure of speech.

A dangling participle is a common and useful shorthand that exists (in English and a great many other languages) precisely because it is useful.

Comment: Maybe useful sometimes, but capable of leading to misunderstanding at other times: "Arising out of a collision between a car and a bus, the bus driver was charged with manslaughter" (adapted from The Complete Plain Words, Fraser, HMSO 1973).

Comment: But aren't other prepositional phrases regarded as including dangling participles? "Before blowing down the trees, I was already fed up with the storm", for example?

Comment: @Araucaria In Wikipedia dangling participle falls under "dangling modifier", I'm not sure if that's a general term for things that are left dangling https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_modifier It has an example of a sentence starting with a prepositional phrase under the heading "Non-participial modifier".  Also at OLO: "It’s not only participial phrases that can dangle and come adrift from their subjects:  they’re part of a wider issue that grammarians describe as ‘floating modifiers, ‘hanging modifiers’, ‘dangling modifiers’ or (again) ‘danglers’." Sorry can't fit link.

Comment: @JeremyC not sure how any of that is relevant to anything I've said. The word "cat", too, is useful sometimes, but capable of leading to misunderstanding at other times. That's not a very helpful thing to point out at all. And what is misleading in your particular example, anyway? Try as I might, I fail to misunderstand it even on purpose. What *is* the wrong reading that Fraser is suggesting that it has? I am not seeing it.

Comment: @Araucaria what the OP has is perfectly fine English. There is nothing wrong with it by any stretch of imagination. Not a word needs to be changed, removed, or added. Everything else that we've said and done on this page so far is completely beside the point.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Yep,  I agree, there's nothing wrong with it whatsoever. And that there's nothing wrong with dangers per se. Just think the PP's a bit of a red lobster.

Comment: "And even more to the point, tell [him] that a dangling participle is not a mistake."



I'm not really in the place to "correct" him.  He's a reviewer of my PhD thesis.  If I don't agree with his advise, I just have to suck it up and change the sentence to something else to avoid the issue.

Comment: The OP's text was not a dangling participle. OK? That does not mean that dangling participles are always OK as @RegDwigHt seems to claim. They can lead the mind of the reader into territory that the writer did not intend. That is what I mean by misleading.

Comment: @JeremyC It might seem like that, but the truth is that *all* ambiguous participial aduncts are bad - dangling or otherwise.

Comment: @JimNewton You could explain to the reviewer that if the main clause is an *It*-extraposition (as this one is), then the subject of any participial in the modifying subordinate clause does not have to be co-referential. the simple reason for this is that the *it* in an extraposition has no meaning and no identity. So it is impossible for any participial clause to have a co-referential subject with it. If they doubt this then ask them what exactly the *it* in *it is useful to* refers to (the answer is nothing; it's non-refrential). Then explain to them that in such cases ...

Comment: @JimNewton  ... such a participial clause would only be considered to be bad/dangling if its subject referred to a different entity from the subject of the *extraposed* clause. In this sentence both of these are unexpressed, but refer to the same people. The subject in each case is something like ***people***. You could paraphrase the sentence like this  "Before **people** define the derivative, it is useful [for **those people** to first define nullability]" .

Comment: @JimNewton The non-extraposed version of that sentence is awkward (which is why we have extrapositions in English, but for the sake of clarity it is "Before people define the deriviative, for those people to first define nullability is useful"

Comment: @JimNewton Lastly, if grammar peeves tried to extend the normal use of the "dangling participle" peeve to *it*-extrapositions, then nobody would ever be able to modify such sentences (which would obviously be ridiculous). By doing this you can avoid insulting your reviewer by telling him that he's silly forworrying about dangling participles. Hope that either helps or makes you feel better/vindicated.